# Javascript to find a href based on keyword text in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

New to Javascript. How can I search a page for text in a certain "p class" and click on the href link next to it? Trying to create a Chrome extension that will open a Twitter link in a new tab. I have a basic extension but stuck here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

How would I find the first href that mentions the Patriots (or any keyword) from a tweet?

HTML of a tweet:

```
<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">
'No chance' Patriots franchise tag Aqib Talib 
<a href="http://t.co/6dV3EHg5WU" rel="nofollow" dir="ltr" data-expanded-url="http://dlvr.it/4tsL8d" class="twitter-timeline-link" target="_blank" title="http://dlvr.it/4tsL8d">
<span class="tco-ellipsis"></span>
<span class="invisible">http://</span>
<span class="js-display-url">dlvr.it/4tsL8d</span>
<span class="invisible"></span>
<span class="tco-ellipsis">_</span>
</span></a></p>
```

Comment: Are you calling any external libraries like jquery?

Comment: Using jQuery this would be much easier indeed. Without it, you're pretty much in need of regular expressions or lengthy dom manipulation syntaxes.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - very new to Javascript/JQuery in Chrome extensions. @qqwy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to find the items to search, do the search in the content yourself and then follow the DOM to get the href from the next link:

```
function findTextAndClick(findText) {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(".tweet-text");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var text = items[i].textContent || items[i].innerText;
        if (text.indexOf(findText) >= 0) {
            var links = items[i].querySelectorAll("a");
            if (links.length) {
                window.location = links[0].href;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Sample usage on your HTML:

```
findTextAndClick("Patriots");
```